# ruby devise create new user

Tags: ruby, devise, cancan

I am using devise and cancan for user signup and signin.  I would like to do some more stuff when a user signs up.  For example set users_roles.  I tried this in the user.rb:

```
after_create :add_default_role
private
def add_default_role
 add_role(:user) if self.roles.blank?
end
```

This works except the record is being added twice to the users_roles table.  How come this events fires twice, and how would be the best way to add a default role?

Thanks

Comment: We would need more information. Can you post the entire user model? Also, the migrations used to create the user/roles tables as well. It is common to add a default role to a user in the database itself.

Comment: please read this blog post about debugging your application http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/